# How can I select an audio input device and capture audio in directshow

Tags: c++, windows-ce, directshow

I am using DirectShow to develop a program in windows embedded ce 6.0.
I write the program in C/C++.

the program needs to deal with **multiple audio input devices**.

I am able to get available audio input devices in directshow, 
but don't know how to specify an input device and capture audio from it.

is there any way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you enumerate audio devices in DirectShow in CE 6.0?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545539

Answer (score 0):

**// firstly, using following code to create audio filter**

```
IBaseFilter * pDevice = NULL;  
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AudioCapture, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC,IID_IBaseFilter,   (void**)&pDevice);
```

**// then, enumerate PIN to get input audio name from filter**

```
IEnumPins * pinEnum = NULL;  
IPin * pin = NULL;  
ULONG fetchCount = 0;  
PIN_INFO pinInfo;  
pDevice->EnumPins(&pinEnum);

while (SUCCEEDED(pinEnum->Next(1, &pin, &fetchCount)) && fetchCount)   
{  
    pin->QueryPinInfo(&pinInfo);  
    if (pinInfo.dir == PINDIR_INPUT)  
    {  
        // get name from pinInfo.achName  
    }  
}
```